# Excel VBA - Making a macro valid for all worksheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with several sheets, (file1, file2, file3, etc), and I'm working on a macro that will parse an external file and paste the contents in the **active** worksheet. 
The issue is that I would like to make my PasteStart below not specific so it will work on **any active worksheet**, not only file1, without specifying its name. I tried using sthg like Variable = ACtiveSheet.Name but I get runtime error 242.

```
Sub Import1()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [file1.C5]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose an XLIFF to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlf (*.xlf),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet

End If
wb2.Close
Range("C5:L3146").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("D6:D2337").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E6:G2307").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set PasteStart = Activesheet.Range("A1")` should work

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams! That did work, however it causes a 400 error after it reaches wb2.Close - any ideas what this may be?

Comment: What's the text of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set PasteStart = Activesheet.Range("A1")
```

should work.

Also:

```
Range("C5:L3146").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("D6:D2337").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E6:G2307").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

should probably be something like:

```
With PasteStart.Parent
    .Range("C5:L3146").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Range("D6:D2337").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Range("E6:G2307").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - the WITH fixed the issue. Thank you so much!